# How do I write to/make changes to an existing squashfs filesystem?

Tags: squashfs

How do I write to/make changes to an existing squashfs filesystem?
I have tried using aufs/unionfs, but these require kernel modules that are extremely hard to compile.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use aufs/unionfs. On a Fedora system for example, install squashfs-tools by doing

```
#yum install squashfs-tools
```

This will get you /sbin/mksquashfs and /usr/sbin/unsquashfs installed on your host machine.
Use these to uncompress an existing squashfs, make changes, and then compress it back again. Like so....

```
#ls rfs.squashfs 
#unsquashfs rfs.squashfs 
#ls rfs.squashfs squashfs
```

Now make changes

```
#cd squashfs
#mkdir etc/vector
```

And compress it back

```
#mksquashfs squashfs my-new-squashfs
```

Comment: Trouble with this solution is, you have to have a crap-ton of space to be able to use `unsquashfs`.

Answer (score 3):

Using (mk|un)squashfs you may loose original permissions, compression type and so on.
So, use unsquashfs -s  to determine useful options.
Also, you may mount -o loop -t squashfs   to review fs
PS: sorry, can't comment